# Regular expression for phone number starting with '00' or '+'

Tags: java, regex

I've got a regex problem: I'm trying to force a phone number beginning with either "00" or "+" but my attempt doesn't work.

```
String PHONE_PATTERN = "^[(00)|(+)]{1}[0-9\\s.\\/-]{6,20}$";
```

It still allows for example "0123-45678". What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Check your character class.

Comment: Why did you enclose `(00)|(+)` in brackets?

Comment: Why no brackets? '00' seems like a subexpression, isn't it? 
@PeterRader, The '+'-part of the validation works fine, but it still allows a single zero at the beginning.

Comment: This problem is not related to JSF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside character class every character is matched literally, which means `[(00)|(+)]` will match a `0 or + or | or ( or )`

Use this regex:

```
 String PHONE_PATTERN = "^(?:00|\\+)[0-9\\s.\\/-]{6,20}$";
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have removed spaces, hyphens and whatever from the number, and you want to catch either +xxnnnnnnnn or 00xxnnnnnnnn where xx is the country code of course and n is the 9 digit number OR 0nnnnnnnnn where a non international number starting with a zero is followed by 9 digits then try this regex

```
 String PHONE_PATTERN = "^(?:(?:00|\+)\d{2}|0)[1-9](?:\d{8})$"
```