# How to match either 0 or + followed by 1 to 3 digit number at the beginning but not both?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following regular expression to check mobile number

```
^(0\d{10,15})$|(?!\1)(\+\d{1,3}\d{10,15})$
```

the string should match either 0 at the beginning followed by 10 to 15 digits

or (but not both)

the string with a `+` at the beginning with 1 to 3 digit country code followed by 10 to 15 digits

the first condition is matched but number with +[country-code] does not

Comment: Like this? `^(?:0|\+{1,3})\d{10,15}$` https://regex101.com/r/2ianGR/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression for phone number starting with '00' or '+'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496178/regular-expression-for-phone-number-starting-with-00-or)

Comment: [Works for valid numbers](https://regex101.com/r/Lz0VwY/1). You might see some invalid ones flagged with a false positive because it's not possible to separate *what* is a country code and what isn't. `+11234567890123456` is invalid if you consider the country code to be `+1` and the number to be `1234567890123456` but it *is*` valid for country codes `+11` (with number `234567890123456`) and `+112` (with number `34567890123456).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
^(?:0|\+[1-9]\d{0,2})\d{10,15}$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:0|\+[1-9]\d{0,2})` - `0` or a `+`, a non-zero digit (`[1-9]`) and then zero, one or two digits (`\d{0,2}`)
- `\d{10,15}` - 10 to 15 digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y9Vd87/3).

Comment: thanks, changed to `^(?:0|\+[1-9]{1,3})\d{10,15}$` so that number with `+0` doesn't pass the regex test

Comment: @UditBhardwaj Then maybe `^(?:0|\+[1-9]\d{0,2})\d{10,15}$` would be better, `\+[1-9]{1,3}` does not allow `102` or `120`.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant could be

```
^(?:0\d{10,15}|\+\d{11,18})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `0\d{10,15}` Match `0` and 10-15 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\+\d{11,18}` Match `+` and 11-18 digits
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aH1CqO/1)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let regex = /^(?:0|\+\d{1,3} ?)\d{10,15}$/;

console.log(regex.test("01234567890"));
console.log(regex.test("0 1234567890"));
console.log(regex.test("+91 1234567898765"));
console.log(regex.test("+91123456789876567576654765675576"));
```